# Consequences of commanding a sentinent creature

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The Purebreath Devotee prestige class gets the ability to rebuke air creatures:

> Rebuke Air Creatures (Su): At 2nd level, the purebreath devotee can rebuke, command, or bolster air creatures as an evil cleric rebukes undead. For the purpose of this ability, she functions like a cleric of her total character level. This ability is usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + her Charisma modifier.

I guess evil clerics commanding undead creatures don't think too much about the consequences. A good-aligned character using above ability on a sentinent creature might face consequences (or possibly even completely violate its good alignment).

The player's handbook does not go into into detail too much on the topic:

> Commanded: A commanded undead creature is under the mental control of the evil cleric. The cleric must take a standard action to give mental orders to a commanded undead. At any one time, the cleric may command any number of undead whose total
> Hit Dice do not exceed his level. He may voluntarily relinquish command on any commanded undead creature or creatures in order to command new ones.

The effect seems to be continuous and probably would only stop if the commanding creature dies or relinquishes it's command over the commanded creature.

Is there any ruling about consequences or moral implications of a character using "rebuke X" ability on a sentinent creature?

Please consider the example, if a level 20 character with 2 levels in purebreath devotee uses rebuke air creatures successfully on a young adult Emerald Dragon (MM2p83) of the creature type Dragon (Air) with 18 HD and 18 INT.

Would the dragon be treated similarly to a loyal companion similarly to a familiar or cohort (leadership)?

What happens to ex-commanded creatures? Is there any ruling indicating whether or not a previously commanded dragon would not be very fond of the ex-commanding creature after the command is relinquished?

Comment: I think that parts of this question may run afoul of the site prohibition on many kinds of alignment questions—see [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/8610). *How does a commanded creature behave?* and similar questions are fine, but the site may resist examining the "moral implications" of commanding. (That's code for *alignment stuff*, right?)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The main intention of the question was to uncover any ruling I am not aware of, that would render questions regarding morale/alignment in connection with this kind of "command" irrelevant. If it boils down to an alignment question that is to be ruled by the DM, that's obviously fine too. The mentioning of alignment was meant as illustrative on how I think it might be an issue and why there may be ruling for that

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an alignment question. https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/are-questions-about-alignment-on-topic

Comment: ...let me expand on that slightly: anything outside of the mechanical effects of alignment is so poorly defined that it is entirely opinion based. That makes answers about "what alignment is doing _____?" firmly opinion-based. So much so that those questions are not stackable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dragon would not be a loyal companion, nor a cohort. As you quote, "A commanded <del>undead</del> creature is under the mental control of the <del>evil cleric</del> character." Your character would in effect be enslaving any intelligent creature they chose to Command, unless your group/DM chooses to "re-fluff" that part of that version of Rebuke as "asking for help".

### Slavery is evil, but is slavery Evil?

Well, it doesn't appear to be Good. The enslaver class (Thayan Slaver, **Unapproachable East**) has the requirement "any Evil", while the escaped slave hunting class (Crimson Scourge, **Cityscape**) has the requirement "any non-Good". This indicates that while **enslaving** sentient creatures may be Evil, maintaining that condition is not necessarily so - slave catchers can be Neutral.

Your character would be actively **enslaving** sentient creatures, rules as written, which sounds evil and Evil to me. Your DM may disagree, of course.

### How would you feel if it happened to you?

If you woke up and realized you had been under the mental domination of another person, would you be very fond towards that person? Or would you be enraged, scared and desiring compensation or retribution?

A released Young Adult Emerald Dragon would, with me as DM, quickly run off to Mommy Dearest, who would stop over for a *Very Loud* chat with your character on their choice to enslave her offspring. And maybe a light snack, to settle her nerves.

### Would this happen?

I point to the above and claim that a Good-aligned character probably would not use the Command ability of Rebuke Air Creature on a sentient creature unless in defense of themselves or others against that creature. I guess someone convincing themselves of the "needs of the many" argument could Command an Emerald Dragon, if they had no other way of defeating a threat to a large population.

However, you would have to be level 18+ in order to do so, which in 3.5 means you should have other ways. In the words of Hannibal, "*aut inveniam viam aut faciam*".

Comment: Great answer. For those not throwing around latin proverbs every day, the Hannibal quote means "I shall either find a way or make one".

Comment: Alignment discussions make (nearly) every answer worse, and this is no exception. Sorry.

Comment: You provided two examples of requested ruling for similar things. Thank you for constructive answer to the question!